# .BAT - найти и удалить файл по имени

Tags: windows, cmd, консоль, bat

Такая проблема:
пытался найти на различных форумах но не нашел решения, мне нужно перебрать все папки в том каталоге где будет запущен файл на наличие конкретного файла, например `file.exe` и удалить его если он имеется. Поиск производить только на один уровень, т.к. известно что искомый файл будет именно на первом уровне. Например исполняемый файл `delete.bat` будет расположен на диске `C:\`, а искомый файл может находится например в папке `C:\papka\file.exe`, таким образом нужно удалить файл `file.exe` как только скрипт его найдёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию маска текущего каталога **.**, то есть тот, откуда вызвана команда. Соответственно, вызываем листинг текущих каталогов и для каждого каталога принудительно удаляем вложенный файл **file.exe*.

```
@for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('@dir /ad /b') do @del /f %~fi\file.exe
```